# excel formula expression to JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

The formula is from the excel is what I wanna implement using JSON object below.

I have the computations but their is error and result not exact, maybe someone has an idea about it. Thanks.

I just wanna know if I made mistake on the convertion. Thanks.
this should be the correct result based on the json

[image]

[image]

#FORMULA

```
=IF(AND(H4="Current",I4<$B$6,J4>$B$6),DAYS360($B$6,J4)/360*12,IF(AND(H4="Current",I4>$B$6,J4>$B$6),DAYS360(I4,J4)/360*12,0))
```

#sample data input (the scheduleData object and effectiveDate input)

```
effectiveDate = new Date('11/1/2021')
    
    
scheduleData=    [
        {
            "description": "Current Term",
            "startDate": "6/1/2021",
            "endDate": "04/30/2025",
            "annualRent": 359659.19999999995
        },
        {
            "noticeDate": "04/30/2028",
            "description": "Current Term - Rent Adjustment",
            "startDate": "05/01/2025",
            "endDate": "04/30/2029",
            "annualRent": 377642.16000000003
        }
    ]


Compute(scheduleData: any):any{
    let startDate = typeof scheduleData.startDate === 'string' ? new Date(scheduleData.startDate):scheduleData.startDate;
    const endDate = typeof scheduleData.endDate === 'string' ? new Date(scheduleData.endDate):scheduleData.endDate;
    if(!startDate || startDate.toString() === 'Invalid Date'){
    }
    let monthlyRent = scheduleData.annualRent / 12;
    let monthsInPeriod = (this.Days360(startDate, endDate) / 360) * 12 
    let rentInPeriod = monthsInPeriod * monthlyRent;
    return { 
      description: scheduleData.description,
      monthlyRent: monthlyRent,
      monthsInPeriod: monthsInPeriod,
      rentInPeriod: rentInPeriod
    }
  }

  Days360(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, decimalPlace: number = 2){
    if(!startDate || !endDate){
      return undefined;
    }
    let startDay = startDate.getUTCDate();
    let endDay = endDate.getUTCDate();

    if(isLastDayOfMonth(startDate)){
      startDay = 30;
    }

    if(isLastDayOfMonth(startDate) && isLastDayOfMonth(endDate)){
      endDay = 30;
    }
    const computedDays = (((endDate.getUTCFullYear() - startDate.getUTCFullYear()) * 360) + ((endDate.getUTCMonth() - startDate.getUTCMonth()) * 30) + (endDay - startDay));
    return parseFloat(parseFloat(computedDays.toString()).toFixed(decimalPlace));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code I did not see to check was the `isLastDayOfMonth` function. I tested your code with the following implementation of `isLastDayOfMonth` and it works:

```
function isLastDayOfMonth(inDate: Date): boolean {
  //april,june,sept,nov
  const thirties = [3, 5, 8, 10];
  //jan,mar,may,jul,aug,oct,dec
  const thOnes = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11];
  if (thirties.includes(inDate.getMonth())) { return inDate.getDate() === 30; }
  if (thOnes.includes(inDate.getMonth())) { return inDate.getDate() === 31; }
  if (inDate.getFullYear() % 4 === 0) { return inDate.getDate() === 29; }
  return inDate.getDate() === 28;
}
```

**Edit:**

I did not see where you took `Effective Date` into consideration in your original code which was also where I was running into issues. The spreadsheet showed `41.97` for the first line and I was getting `46.97`.

With the following code ([in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-z0IxQixInEkjSOGppRq0BAmN4dqHIUEGFHak7AGg8jAlmui4MAcAmHS8gAEa5qKbBWKQoi4fhdziJOCBpNo44nGclwSlMtwwOc0HBg4oYjoiyIUYg1FaJi9auA8ACy6aiq6Tw8lAYkdt8KbCdGRoAPIILJBISYxUnwssAhCfc0YAJpwB4mlKYUUTSQAYnoujGR48n6RM6nqKKbFwJZ8IuY5Tg4tB5iqS5blqtpMY+c4qYTPZ7jBQ6HnWbZ0WOfp57YKcyCNhhsVBQAtAZnguQpMBaLgAVqemaWyplPhxmVuX5dUdXpkV5gme4lUZT0WUkFFbUwHlVTRUIKW3h1uZdXAALeKaoq8hwMC9qN6XjRIcAtW1Y3VVNhQzSQM01q1HibRNw2+amWjLdVrwkaKh3tZdE3bQQM0ANTtgSEDHatT2lvNb0lU1HZfRhw7wtxMCKB4EBwFZuggPgNCQ+40Ow-DUA0BdVUTdd8jPG8HxzN8vB41ZaAAB7aBjKBIShaEYbwelYkCMWUk0ooANocTAABEK7ADOc5gNzJjczIiLPjAAAqubyNzj7c5JcDCzz-KsMwnDcHL0Lc+5yvcxwAAszBzerXAAKxa043O0vSuiDsrvJmwAnPyztRAwTue17Xtm4IGJblz3NgCA6AYd4euG8bHCm2wAAcls83zAsbnrYvuBL0vuPI-UwIOMAAIJaAAVqI0DyGSCcK1pSsixwZvMBw7Dm5Xuu10bJsa07lc2wyFcmLyADsA-8gbbDu4KHCT1PHC8n7ggALrDazYwICA7gAKLoeoNBiBIgsuloREYCAoK0Z0EAgPoURw+kNByEoKhFBAh+MwIQA)), I was able to get the results accurately:

```
const effectiveDate = new Date('11/1/2021');

function Compute(scheduleData: any): any {
  let startDate = typeof scheduleData.startDate === 'string' ? new Date(scheduleData.startDate) : scheduleData.startDate;
  const endDate = typeof scheduleData.endDate === 'string' ? new Date(scheduleData.endDate) : scheduleData.endDate;
  if (!startDate || startDate.toString() === 'Invalid Date') {
    return scheduleData;
  }
  let monthlyRent = scheduleData.annualRent / 12;
  let range360: any = (startDate < effectiveDate && endDate > effectiveDate) ?
    Days360(effectiveDate, endDate) :
    (startDate > effectiveDate && endDate > effectiveDate) ?
      Days360(startDate, endDate) :
      0;
  let monthsInPeriod = (range360 / 360) * 12;
  let rentInPeriod = monthsInPeriod * monthlyRent;
  return {
    description: scheduleData.description,
    monthlyRent: monthlyRent,
    monthsInPeriod: monthsInPeriod,
    rentInPeriod: rentInPeriod
  };
}

function Days360(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, decimalPlace: number = 2): number | undefined {
  if (!startDate || !endDate) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
  let startDayOfMonth = startDate.getDate();
  let startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
  let endMonth = endDate.getMonth();
  let endDayOfMonth = endDate.getDate();
  let endYear = endDate.getFullYear();

  let monthsDifference = endMonth - startMonth;
  let dayOfMonthDifference = endDayOfMonth - startDayOfMonth;
  let yearDifference = endYear - startYear;

  let monthsDifferenceInDate360 = 30 * monthsDifference;
  let yearDifferenceInDate360 = 360 * yearDifference;

  let differenceSum = yearDifferenceInDate360 + monthsDifferenceInDate360 + dayOfMonthDifference;
  return parseFloat(parseFloat(differenceSum.toString()).toFixed(decimalPlace));
}
var scheduleData = [{
  "description": "Current Term",
  "startDate": "6/1/2021",
  "endDate": "04/30/2025",
  "annualRent": 359659.19999999995
},
{
  "noticeDate": "04/30/2028",
  "description": "Current Term - Rent Adjustment",
  "startDate": "05/01/2025",
  "endDate": "04/30/2029",
  "annualRent": 377642.16000000003
}
];

scheduleData.forEach(function (sd): void {
  console.log(Compute(sd));
});
```

Comment: so do you mean my interpretation of the excel formula is correct Sir?

Comment: do you have stackblitz or any implementation Sir that I could check ?

Comment: I believe your interpretation is correct, based on the correct result screenshot and the calculations I received.

Comment: how about the effectiveDate  Sir?

Comment: how about my Compute function Sir that gets the months in period , monthly rent , and rent in period ?

Comment: I think the Compute function is fine, the effectiveDate is fine, but it's possible the Date360 implementation is the culprit actually. In the [DAYS360](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/days360-function-b9a509fd-49ef-407e-94df-0cbda5718c2a) formula, it gets the difference between date1 and date2 considering only the difference between months, difference between dates of the month, and difference between the years in each, individually. The `isLastDayOfMonth` is probably not needed. I'll try to add additional details to my answer if it can help.

Comment: It took a minute, but I believe the code I just added to my answer should be sufficient. Your algorithm was only missing a few details, but it was definitely a good conversion. Any changes that I made in my code from yours were mostly personal preferences or just to help it work on my end. If you're ever struggling, feel free to [modularize](https://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html) your code a bit to be able to separate parts of a function and be able to bug hunt faster. I did not do much of that in my code, but I could append my answer again for that if needed.

Comment: Thanks Sir , can we also try to add Sir if its get the correct total based on this one https://imgur.com/a/MVPP8nl

Comment: Hi @phentil , what if startdate is empty ? on the excel the data is still computing even if there is no start date https://imgur.com/a/r7cgky4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237462/discussion-between-phentnil-and-ananya-amar).

Comment: While I appreciate your confidence in my abilities, I must request that you ask a new question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I will do what I can to help out, but I would like to see other stackoverflow users answer your questions (they won't see it here).